# use subdomains in a CodeIgniter program, like a blogging system

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I am starting a project which it's structure is somehow like a blogging system.
Users will use an address like : "username.mydomain.com" to see their profile, and this request should be handeled like they are visiting " mydomain.com/index.php/profile_viewer/username "

First problem is this, when you are sending the request for the subdomain, the host searches between the defined subdomains that are pointing to a directory with the same name. how should I handle all requests to a single file?

And the next problem is how should I get the subdomain name in my php program and pass it to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just making a wild guess that you're using Apache2 as your web server.

In Apache, you can set up a website (using sites-available) in which all subdomains load a certain set of website files (PHP). For example:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
```

Now when someone goes to a subdomain, like `tommy.example.com` Apache will load your set of web files from `/home/example/public_html`. You can then identify the subdomain with PHP and/or CodeIgniter using your preferred method (e.g. `$_SERVER`).

Comment: thanks for your solution, but I am running my website in a shared hosting and I don't have access to Apache configuration files. In this condition, what should I do?

Comment: You might think about a different structure in that case, something like `example.com/user/username`
If you must use subdomains, you'll need something more powerful than shared hosting (as far as I know). There are inexpensive VPS plans which give you full control over this type of configuration. Many plans under $10/mo http://lowendbox.com/